# Show the equivalence of the limit definition of the derivative of a vector valued function $DF(x)v = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{F(x+hv) - F(x)}{h}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Let $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, I need to show that $DF(x)v = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{F(x+hv) - F(x)}{h}$, $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $F(x) = \begin{bmatrix} F_1(x) \\ \vdots \\ F_n(x) \end{bmatrix}$

Using the definition of $DF(x)$, I have,

$DF(x)v = \begin{bmatrix} \sum_i v_i \dfrac{\partial F_1(x)}{\partial x_i} \\ \vdots \\ \sum_i v_i \dfrac{\partial F_n(x)}{\partial x_i} \end{bmatrix}$

Then I apply the definition of partial derivative to get,

$DF(x)v = \begin{bmatrix} \sum_i v_i \dfrac{\partial F_1(x)}{\partial x_i} \\ \vdots \\ \sum_i v_i \dfrac{\partial F_n(x)}{\partial x_i} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \sum_i v_i \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{F_1(x+he_i)-F_1(x)}{h} \\ \vdots \\ \sum_i v_i\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{F_n(x+he_i)-F_n(x)}{h} \end{bmatrix}  $

where $e_i = \begin{bmatrix} 0, \ldots, 1, \ldots, 0\end{bmatrix}^T$, where $1$ occupies the $i$th position

All in all, this gets me,

$DF(x)v = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \dfrac{F(x+h \mathbb{1}) - F(x)}{h}$, $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, where $\mathbb{1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1, \ldots, 1, \ldots 1 \end{bmatrix}^T$
Which is not the same? How do I move the $v_i$ in to the argument? I am thinking maybe a slight change of variable.

Comment: I feel like if you do such an explicit computation, you're in essence going to be proving the chain rule in a special case. Would you like to see a solution which directly applies the chain rule?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes, anything helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\lambda: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}^n$ by $\lambda(t) = x + tv$. Then, the limit you're trying to compute is $(F \circ \lambda)'(0)$. Hence, we can apply the chain rule to this:
\begin{align}
(F \circ \lambda)'(0) &= F'(\lambda(0)) \cdot \lambda'(0) \\
&= F'(x) \cdot v
\end{align}
Here $F'(x)$ is the matrix representation of the linear transformation $DF(x): \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^m$... so it's just the matrix of partial derivatives. Also, the $\cdot$ denotes matrix multiplication. This is precisely what you wanted to prove.

---

**Additional Remarks:**

I would highly recommend you to read Loomis and Sternberg's excellent book [Advanced Calculus](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf), in particular section $3.7$, up to theorem $7.2$. There, they give a nice geometric meaning to the directional derivatives, and how it relates to differentiability, and also explain how to use it in chain rule computations like above.

By the way you only asked about the special case $F: \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^n$, but the same proof I showed above works in even more general settings, when the domain and target of $F$ are arbitrary normed-vector spaces; they don't even have to be the same.